# Aligning logos in the header and adding header text

Tags: header-footer, logos

I am trying to align the two logos I have in the header of my report. As you can see, the right logo sits somewhat below the left one. I would like to align these two by shifting the right one up and also add one more line of text below it.

My code and the resulting layout look like this at the moment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage[a4paper,
            bindingoffset=0pt,
            left=2cm,
            right=1.75cm,
            top=1.25cm,
            bottom=1cm,
            headheight=1.25cm,
            headsep=0.9cm,
            footskip=1.5cm,
            includehead,
            includefoot
            ]{geometry}

%Set header and footer using the fancyhdr package
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\lhead{\includegraphics[height=1.4cm]{logos/eth_logo.png}} % left logo
\rhead{\includegraphics[height=0.9cm]{logos/ibk_logo.png}} % right logo
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove rule below header
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the two logos you are using to your question. Otherwise, any solution that works with dummy images may not work for you.

Comment: If I just post the images, will you be able to download them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting both images into `\chead` we can use `valign=t` from the `adjustbox` package for vertical alignment. We can then add the extra line of space on a new line with a negative `\vspace`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{mwe}%<-- just for sample images
\usepackage{lipsum}%<-- just for sample text
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}%<--

\usepackage[a4paper,
            bindingoffset=0pt,
            left=2cm,
            right=1.75cm,
            top=1.25cm,
            bottom=1cm,
            headheight=1.25cm,
            headsep=0.9cm,
            footskip=1.5cm,
            includehead,
            includefoot
            ]{geometry}

%Set header and footer using the fancyhdr package
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\chead{
\includegraphics[height=1.4cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}
\hfill
\includegraphics[height=0.9cm, valign=t]{example-image-b}\\
\vspace{-.4cm}
\ \hfill An extra line of text
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove rule below header
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]